# Why am I getting different behaviours for scollview between emulators and physical devices?

Tags: nativescript

I'm a newcomer to NativeScript. I was playing around to replicate a common UI pattern used by weather apps. I achieved a similar look working fine on the emulator (I've tested on Android versions 4.4, 6 and 9 and all works fine) but it doesn't work as I expected on physical devices ( Bottom pane doesn't scroll, tested on 3 different devices with Android versions 4.4, 6 and 7). I've created a [playground project](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=FQOBKU&v=2). My question is why am I getting different behaviours for the [bottom scollview](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=FQOBKU&v=2) between emulators and physical devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android Emulators may not give the accuracy in some cases, after all you are not really dealing with a real touch interface there.

Also Android has an extended version of ScrollView just to support nested scrolls, you will have to extend the NativeScript ScrollView to use [androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/widget/NestedScrollView)

```
var __extends = this.__extends || function (d, b) {
    for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p];
    function __() { this.constructor = d; }
    __.prototype = b.prototype;
    d.prototype = new __();
};

var scrollView = require("tns-core-modules/ui/scroll-view");

var NestedScrollView = (function (_super) {
    __extends(NestedScrollView, _super);
    function NestedScrollView() {
        _super.call(this);
    }
    NestedScrollView.prototype.createNativeView = function () {
        if (typeof android !== void 0) {
            return new androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView(this._context);
        }
        return _super.prototype.createNativeView.call(this);
    };
    return NestedScrollView;
})(scrollView.ScrollView);

exports.NestedScrollView = NestedScrollView;
```

[Updated Playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=FQOBKU&v=4)

Answer (score 0):

I could use a little more info, but this might be due to the nature of `ScrollView`.

If the screen is large enough to display all of the content declared inside of the `ScrollView` tags, then it will not be scroll-able.

Is that the issue you are experiencing?

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for your answer but that's not the case. I've explicitly set a height for the bottom scrollview to make sure the content overflows.